# zsh auto suggestion in android studio windows 10

Tags: android-studio, terminal, git-bash, oh-my-zsh

I decided to customize the Android Studio terminal and used zsh, but when I install the auto suggestion plugin in Android Studio, I encounter this problem.

[image]

also this is my terminal settings

[image]

Comment: zsh is not bash (and vice versa): it's not really clear what is going on since the window label seems to be "git bash terminal", so maybe it's using bash even though you told it to use zsh, or maybe it's just mislabeled. Either way whatever shell you are using is trying to use escape sequences to control the displayed text, and these are failing. Git itself is not relevant here: only the shell and its setup and the terminal emulator and its setup matter.

Comment: The solution I found for Windows was to use wsl2, which by installing zsh can have bash in different IDEs.